# Need clarification regarding Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

Tags: f#

We have a project build with F# 3.1 using Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.  Now we are trying to build this project with VS2015 and we have the problems with this part of F#. For example, when I am trying to install it using Nuget it requires F# 3.1. I use [this guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx) and it looks outdated.

So I will be thankful for answers on my questions:

1. What part of F# language Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders belongs to? It is F# core library or it is one of external libraries? Who is responsible for this library? Where can I find the bug tracker for this part of F# ecosystem?
2. Is there anybody who trying to use [this tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361033.aspx) to build F# application in VS2015? Do you have a problems like me?  Or all is working fine?
3. What is the current state of Microsoft.FSharp.TypeProviders? Is it outdated and all what I need is to wait some time when the library will be adopted to F# 4.0 and VS2015.  Or do I need to switch to other DB-access library?

**Here is full description to reproduce error:**

- New Project - F# - Console Application (net 4.6)
- NuGet - Install Data.TypeProviders. `packages.config`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <packages>
     <package id="FSharp.Core.3" version="0.0.2" targetFramework="net46" />
     <package id="FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" version="0.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
    </packages>
  ```
- To `program.fs` add the lines:

  ```
  module Test
     open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
     type internal DB = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
  ```

Here is an error message:

> The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools can not be found

[image]

Comment: What is "Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeLibrary"? EDIT: From the link, I guess you were referring to `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.dll`. I'm not sure what the answer is though.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, it was my mistake - TypeProviders. First of all, it requires F# 3.0. Second, I can not use Dbml from this library in VS2015. So I am just wondering what is recommended way to work with MS SQL in F# 4.0 ?

Comment: I have seen some reports regarding this issue - looks like VS 2015 does not create some registry key that F# expects. Aside from that, I think it should still work - though this is something that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Where is the best place to send report about it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some more historical background:

> 1.What part of F# language Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders belongs to? It is F# core library or it is one of external libraries? Who is responsible for this library? Where can I find the bug tracker for this part of F# ecosystem?

It's not part of the core runtime, i.e. you can be a happy and productive F# dev without ever interacting with it. It was created by Microsoft and shipped with F# 3.0/VS 2012 as a set of in-the-box type providers for common Msft data stacks. Type providers as a language feature were added in the same release, so this library was a bit of a showcase of what could be done. FS.D.TP is not actively maintained at the moment. Original version 4.3.0.0 is still shipped in the box with VS 2013 and VS 2015, but no changes have been made since the VS 2012 release.  Source is available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/tree/fsharp4/src/fsharp/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders) and you are welcome to file bugs in that repo, too.

In principle the library be taken over as a community project and maintained/updated from there as a nuget package. Nothing is really preventing this. However having the library in the box with Msft signature and support is very important to a lot of enterprise customers still. So it persists in this sort of limbo state where it's in the box but not updated.

> 3.What is the current state of Microsoft.FSharp.TypeProviders? Is it outdated and all what I need is to wait some time when the library will be adopted to F# 4.0 and VS2015. Or do I need to switch to other DB-access library?

Some of this is answered above. The library should still be perfectly functional with F# 3.1 or F# 4.0, provided you have all of the required dependencies. In particular, you need the .NET 4.0 or 4.5 SDK installed (you can get Win8/.NET 4.5 SDK [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx)) because the TPs rely on various executable codegen tools (sqlmetal.exe, svutil.exe) that come along therewith.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that installing Win8/.NET 4.5 SDK fixes the problem.

Comment: The installer for the Win8/.NET 4.5 SDK crashes during installation on my Win10/.NET 4.6 machine. The latest Win10 SDK installs but that does not fix the problem for me.

Comment: @JonHarrop I also had a similiar issue. My home PC worked fine, but this makes sense since it was upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10. My work PC i could not get this to work at all, new windows 10 install. I got it to work by launching the SDK setup and telling it to download for another machine. I only downloaded the Windows SDK and .net4.5 SDK (although i am sure it doesn't matter if you download them all) I then just chose to install those 2 SDK's and bam everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

I just created a new project in VS 2015 targeting F# 4.0 (4.4.0.0) on .NET 4.6, added a reference to `FSharp.Data.TypeProviders` using NuGet, which lead to the following `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FSharp.Core.3" version="0.0.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" version="0.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

I then added a new file and entered

```
module Test
 open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
 type internal DB = SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OBSCURED_CATALOG;Integrated Security=SSPI;">
 let private e1 = DB.GetDataContext().OBSCURED_ENTITY
```

Then, VS told me to reference `System.Data.Linq`... everything works just as it should and the tutorial looks up-to-date as well.

Did you already try to set up a new project instead of migrating the old one?

**TL;DR** (see [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84956/discussion-between-rch-and-demas))

Problem is that some registry keys were missing. If your registry doesn't contain

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A]
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\"
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ProductName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x64]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\x64\\"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86]
"ProductVersion"="8.1.51641"
"ComponentName"="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK"
"InstallationFolder"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v8.1A\\bin\\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\\"
```

it might be time to (re)install Windows SDK for Windows 8.

Comment: Can you please add `type dbml = DbmlFile<"MyDatabase.dbml", ContextTypeName = "MyDataContext">` to your project? (It is from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/hh361039.aspx).  We want to store connection string in the configuration file.  This line give me error:  `TypeProviders: The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools can not be found`  even on new project.  I think you don't need to create dbml file to make this check. Thanks.

Comment: adding this gives `The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: Could not find file '...\MyDatabase.dbml'. F ...\F.fs` so at least the type provider is found. Are the type providers enabled in Tools -> Options -> F# Tools -> Type Providers?

Comment: Yes, all providers are enabled. Moreover I have error even with your code. I have updated my question and described all steps to reproduce error.  Can you please share your project (github or something else) ?

Comment: I have exactly the same error with your project: `TypeProviders: The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools can not be found`.  For example for line `type dbml = DbmlFile` I had error ` Could not find file '...\MyDatabase.dbml'`, but when I have added this file the error was `TypeProviders: The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools can not be found`.  I have a fresh install of Windows 10 and VS2015 Community Edition.  What would you recommend to check?

Comment: Did you choose to install F# when you installed VS or did you do a default install and follow the instructions when first opening an F# project?

Comment: I have full installation of VS2015 Community Edition. And I can compile every of my projects which is not used TypeProviders. I'll try to install tomorrow VS215 on Windows 8.1 and check the project again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84956/discussion-between-rch-and-demas).

Comment: just for information.  The reinstall didn't help me.  I even created a new virtual machine and installed Windows 10 + VS2015 from scratch.  The same result.  And event Windows 8 + VS2015 too.   But then I have installed `Windows Software Development Kit (SDK) for Windows 8` as @latkin have recommended and it helped me on all systems.  anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the update. I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. VS 2015 project upgraded to VS 2017 / .NET 4.7.2 / F# 4.1 (F# Core 4.4.3.0)

Suddenly Microsoft.FSharp.Data only contained namespace "UnitSystems".

"WsdlService" would not compile.

---

Installed the following Nuget packages:

nuget "FSharp.Data.TypeProviders" and "FSharp.Compiler.Tools" (?)

and everything compiles with latest VS 2017 / .NET 4.7.2 ...

(Note: I also removed references to System.ValueTuple)