# F# SQL Server Type Provider .NET SDK tools not found. Windows 10

Tags: sql-server, sdk, f#, windows-10, type-providers

Running Windows 10, Visual Studio Community 2015, and SQL Server 2014 Express. I also have .Net 3.5, 4.0, 4.5 installed.

My SqlDataConnection is throwing the compile time error "The type provider 'Microsoft.FSharp...' ... Error reading schema. The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found". Searching for solutions I got directed to some registry keys.

In

```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
```

I have two keys: \v8.0A and \v8.1A. (I didn't have a key for any v7.xxx) I got to these keys from one online answer to this issue. Each of those keys has three keys under it: WinSDK-NetFx...Tools. For v8.0A the ellipses are "35" and for v8.1A they are "40". Plus each key is repeated with + "-x64" and + "-x86".

These six keys all have string values of "InstallationFolder" (as well as "ComponentName" and "ProductVersion").

I go to the installation folders, and each one has ResGen.exe and SqlMetal.exe (which are the files other answers said to look for). So it seems like I have the requisite registry keys which point to the requisite exe's.

Next to the installation folders for v7.0A and v8.1A, I also have one for v10.0A. So I tried creating some additional registry keys named v10.0A. In those v10.0A keys I tried putting the v10.0A folder as the InstallationFolder and I also tried putting the v8.1A folder as the installationFolder. (One reason I tried this permutation is because the error message asks for SDK 4.0 or 4.5, whereas the v10.0A folder has NETFX 4.6 Tools. So I tried to resolve possible inconsistency between v4.5 and v4.6 by varying the registry keys under v10.0A and using the path to v4.5 in the v8.1A folder.)

I've probably gone on too long trying to give the pertinent info. But I have the most current software installed and updated, and I"m trying to follow previous solutions given. And I'm stuck. Maybe all the newest versions aren't yet gotten tied together with each other?

Any help appreciated much.

Edit: Doing some more web searching, I'm now finding more fixes with more details. This one in particular looks very promising:

[Need clarification regarding Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31770226/need-clarification-regarding-microsoft-fsharp-data-typeproviders)

But I won't get to work on it until the end of today. So that link may be my answer, but I can't confirm for a bit.

Comment: Did you try to install https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx ?

Comment: That did it. Thanks. Easy enough. Sorry I got sidetracked from being more timely with this. But that install got me past the error. (I have a new error now, but I should be able to figure it out. And this error is reflective of the process now working.)

Comment: related with more info: http://stgaup.blogspot.com/2016/02/the-net-sdk-40-or-45-tools-could-not-be.html

Answer (score 0):

Worth checking you are using the [nuget version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/) of the F# type providers. The version bundled with the framework does not have the [fix applied](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/638) that extends the list of registry keys searched to cope with later versions of the SDK (as would be installed on Windows 10)

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/issues/21#issuecomment-337444919